# Measuring mains - shifting ground from mains to bridge

Tags: ground, measurement

The circuit below is a simplified and partial front end schematic of a solution that measures main voltages and takes action if over voltage, under voltage or "wrong voltage" (e.g. user plugged into 220 Vac and appliance is not automatic). Main measurement should be within 1% error.

EDIT: fixing U4 connection.
EDIT2: updating figure
[image]

(Still need a DC shift before R4 reaches secondary ground. Or dual supply to the op amps.)

From the rectifier bridge, a LM317 supplies power to all the ICs (not shown). Under_voltage, Over_voltage and Wrong_voltage are triggers, coming from comparators and going into latches and logic (also not shown)). A NO relay at the end of the circuit must be activated to allow appliance to be main powered (just guess, not shown lol).

There is a difference between the secondary and the bridge references, indicated on the schematic by the common ground and chassis ground (should be earth gnd, but no such symbol in LTSpice :) ). The difference is, of course, a 0.7 V diode drop, and I should account for it in measurement.

One way to go is just use an instrumentation amp, and that ground shift is solved. But that looks like an overkill, since I don't need all the CMRR, either extra high input impedance an instrumentation amp has to offer. Also, it is somewhat expensive (although I've just found a $0.54/1k unit in amp: http://www.ti.com/product/ina332).

A differential amp would be not ideal, since I can't cheaply match input resistances (at least not precisely), and I have surprisingly found that the cheapest diff. amps is more expansive than the INA332 in amp mentioned above: http://www.ti.com/product/ina154. I am not sure if other manufacturers follow this price tag as well.

I was considering maybe using a charge pump for powering the ICs, then there is no 0.7 V drop. In the charge pump case, its power capability should be well calculated - just closing a miniature 10A relay might need about 30mA, indefinitely.

What do you think, can you suggest me a strategy? Keep the bridge and deal with the ground shift, going with the charge pump, or something else?

Comment: Why not just measure the DC voltage across C1? As it stands, your circuit is trying to measure AC voltage which is harder to do than DC as it keeps changing.

Comment: And, by the way, your inputs to U4 are the wrong way round.

Comment: @Finbarr This solution is meant to protect other equipment from "wrong" voltages and last at least 10 years. Since I need an electrolyctic cap on C1, degradation will probably be an issue for measurement. OTOH, degradation may not pose a problem to the LM317, since it can handle some ripple. After many years and possible severe degradation, in case there is no proper rectified supply for the LM317, all the circuits above go down.  In this case, that is not a safety issue, because there is a NO relay at the end.

Comment: @Finbarr Furthermore, I can't say the temperature my circuit will be exposed to, and that may add to C1 degradation, and finally leakage current may be a problem to measurement. So I'd rather measure the secondary and compare the peak with a reference. Any trigger will be latched, so I don't think it will be any harder.

Comment: @Finbarr U4 input fixed. Thank you, that is a "late night"  effect...

Comment: So, do you plan on having these lights blink at 60Hz? Because that's what this circuit does. (unless your reference is also AC) Vsec needs to be after the amplfier. Second thing: if you have any loads (switching) that are not constant after the transformer this may not work.

Comment: @laptop2d Thank you for your reply. Some notes: > So, do you plan on having these lights blink at 60Hz? Because that's what this circuit does. 
Lights blink? Sorry, I don't follow your idea... No lights in my circuit, and that is not what my circuit does. It first lowers voltage from main, then after after a carefully planned voltage divider, it compares the voltage to a reference.

Comment: @laptop2d >Second thing: if you have any loads (switching) that are not constant after the transformer this may not work.

You are right, but this circuit serves the only purpose of protecting the following device. There is nothing powered by the transformer but an LM317, a quad buffer, a quad comparator, a latch and a miniature relay. All combined is below 100mA.

Answer (score 1):

The Vsec voltage is an AC voltage ( in addition of being offset to GND ) so you will get square waves off the comparators.
A small-signal diode connected to positive terminal of C1 plus a non-electrolytic cap will give you a GND referenced DC voltage that can be checked for under/over/other voltage conditions.

Comment: That is still referenced to the bridge rectifier ground, and not to secondary. There is no need to rectify it to DC. But OTOH, your idea gets me rid of the problem that I either need a positive DC shift before the voltage divider reaches the secondary ground, or a dual supply for the op amps. Also, the slight voltage variation on the diodes are well within the 1% error budget.

Comment: But thinking again, the C1 cap would prevent any event coming from main at one cycle time scale. C1 would smooth too much!

Comment: If you need fast response from the over/under voltage circuit  connect a diode from + output of the bridge to the C1 cap and connect the resistor divider directly across bridge output.

Comment: Yes, user117884. I believe that is the cheapest solution. I'll try it and see how it fits with everything else. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Unless you just want a trigger on an overvoltage spike (a bit hard to open a relay in time to do anything about that though) you will need to rectify the voltage you are going to be measuring anyway to make it DC, so you might as well measure across the capacitor, this will also help it to not be triggered by transients that will be soaked up in a basic filter and do not pose a risk.

Is the device to be powered drawing from the rectified output? If not then you need a resistor to discharge the capacitor or it will not detect undervoltages.

Optically isolated amplifiers are an alternative for crossing awkward ground level differences and would allow you to safely measure voltages on the primary side, here's a common one that doesn't even need a power supply for the input side: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2212115.pdf
They cost about $1 though.

Edit:
Ah good I see. If you want a very tight limit on line voltage you will want to measure it directly rather than from the secondary of the transformer. Put a bridge rectifier across the line and measure voltages from that. The upper limit is easy and can be implemented how you did in the question, the low voltage limit will need an averaging circuit though.

(voltage regulators and comparator references and some other stuff omitted but you get the idea)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWBwj7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The overvoltage comparator will be triggered if the peak exceeds the reference by enough and for enough cycles. The undervoltage comparator will be triggered every cycle if the voltage is high enough before being passed through an integrator and comparator, if the input does not spend enough time above the minimum voltage each cycle the undervoltage signal will be triggered. The decay of the integrators can be adjusted with the pots to control the sensitivity, the dividers should have a much higher resistance than the pots if you use them.

I would highly recommend not sensing through a transformer unless you do not need much accuracy, or if you do then use one that is a fair bit larger than required to power the circuit, rectifiers are a lot cheaper than larger transformers though and you do not need the isolation. I would definitely not use the capacitor for the power supply as an integrator though, it will have much too long a response time for one that is big enough to remove ripple for the op-amp supply and you will use a lot of power for the size of decay resistor you would need for the size of capacitor.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated the circuit. It is still simplified, but more complete than before. This circuit is intended to deal with sags and swells that last over a cycle. Release time of a relay is ~ 5 msec, so total response time will be within a cycle (50 or 60Hz). It is also intended to protect against wrong voltages (eg, user plugged into 220V, and the appliance is designed for 110/127V). This circuit is not concerned with fast spikes. Yes, optical isolated amps and instumentation amps are the usual choices for dealing with incompatible ground levels.

Comment: But there is no need to rectify the AC for measurement. AC can be compared against a DC reference, provided that all that matters is the peak value.

Comment: The device to be powered is not powered by the rectified output. It is powered by a main line. The first (maybe only) purpose of the bridge rectifier is to provide a DC value for powering the ICs. So C1 should indeed keep voltage from bridge smooth enough for the LM317 to operate properly.

Comment: Ah good, opamps are usually quite resistant to supply noise anyway. I've added things to my answer that I hope are what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you TWiz. We can avoid using 2 bridges using what @user117884 suggested: just a diode between the bridge and C1. Also, I believe that the error contribution form the xfrm and the Vdrop variations will be quite below the 1% error budget for measurement. You are right about the integrator, otherwise fast spikes may trigger the latch. So it is probably a good idea to have an low sensitivity integrator before over and under voltages comparators. I'll test it on the bench and let you know.

Comment: Just for clarification, the 1 cycle response is not a requirement, but just the time response of the previous circuit, that does not have integrators, and the time response is dominated by the relay.

Comment: >Detecting undervoltage on a single cycle would require an AC reference to compare the input to. I don't understand why you say so. If the AC voltage is compared directly to a DC reference, at any moment the peak is greater than the ref., you have a trigger. But then there is the fast spikes issue, that requires an integrator or filter and that is what takes longer.

Comment: *Sorry, can't embed pictures here... See circuit and simulation[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: http://imgur.com/a/yO98F
  [2]: http://imgur.com/a/4iKw8

Comment: Overvoltage can be detected on a single cycle but you only want to do that if your load can't accept several cycles of high voltage or, otherwise put an integrator on the overvoltage too. The undervoltage needs to be integrated with a long enough decay that it will not be triggered when the input crosses zero every cycle, and so it will have a response time of a few cycles unless you do not use an integrator and compare the input against an AC reference, although you could test that the input exceeds the minimum and trigger if it does not happen for a few cycles.

Comment: In fact that you might want to do that, input the un-integrated signal to an op-amp that triggers when the signal exceeds the undervoltage limit, then integrate that, I will add a diagram of this.

Comment: Oh my! How could I not see that by comparing under voltage directly to a dc, it would trigger every cycle... Your approach seems nice, I'll test it on the bench and let you know.